# Scrypt with weak parameters, for proof of work?

Tags: proof-of-work, scrypt

I need a proof of work/memory that takes about 100ms to complete, and as short time as possible to validate. Hashing random values and a nounce to get enough leading zeroes is my current approach, and my plan was to use blake2 for the hash function, but I couldn't get it to work. I did however get scrypt to work, but it's obviously a lot slower, and even when reducing parameters below recommended values, the speed isn't great.

Does it make sense to use a proof of work where the work is only 32-256 times larger than the work required to validate it? Should i look for another approach?

Comment: If your premise is that you want a proof-of-work scheme, you should look for something designed to be a proof-of-work scheme like [equihash](https://www.cryptolux.org/images/b/b9/Equihash.pdf).  But you should consider carefully whether you really want to invent a new reason to burn fossil fuels.